# Odd Xuggler behaviour in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, transcoding, xuggler

I have a Xuggler class which converts a given media format to mp3. This works with most things I throw at it, however on occasion I come across some flv files which causes the application to crash inside eclipse.

When I attempt to run the class in debug on the file in question, it actually executes and finishes correctly, even with a valid mp3 file output! This is reproducible too, it happens with all test runs I've done in debug mode and I have cross checked to make sure that same file crashes the application in normal execution.

No matter what I've tried I cannot get some flv files to convert under normal running conditions.

Is there anything extra eclipse is doing in debug mode which is causing this odd effect?

**Edit**

More specifically, the crash occurs on the call to IContainer#open

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a non-issue.

I just tried running it after I exported the project to a runnable .jar and it works perfectly. I'll just have to work with debug mode to perform proper testing before shipping.